# Nested routes and template replacement in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I try to develop a simple Ember.js app.

I think that these screens describe the desired scenario good enough.

1. [image: Index]
2. [image: Movies list]
3. [image: Movie detailed info]

Buttons on the top are #link-tos. Note that I want the first button to be highlighted on the 3rd screen.

It's easy to find examples where the 3rd template lives in the outlet in the 2nd one, but I need some kind of template replacement in the main outlet.

Please help me to achieve this behavior. Hope that my description is clear enough.

Comment: What do you call the **"first button"**? I see the first button is highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make list and detail routes same level, so they both are rendered to the same outlet, one at time. Like that:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("movies", function() {
        this.route("list");
        this.route("view", {path:"view/:movie_id"});
    });
});

App.MoviesIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   redirect : function() {
      this.transitionTo('movies.list');
   }
});
```

All the rest is done as allways